# chrome devtools sidebar pane, set multi titled object

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

During developing chrome extension faced difficulties with creating multi title sidebar pane.

According to the manual `setObject` set object as side bar content, but only with single title:

```
sidebar.setObject({ some: 'qwe' }, 'title');
```

and result is following:

[image]

but my target is to set object to meet following:

[image]

I'v tried to use multi `setObject`, but, as i expected, it doesen't append data, it overwrite it. I know about `setPage`, and ability to set such object via JS, but i'm intrested in solution with plain chrome API
tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use [setObject](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/devtools/front_end/extensions/ExtensionPanel.js#l300) for this purpose because it always does a remove of previous objects (on Line 307) as in your testing. So there is only ever one object with one header/title section.

If you look at the source of the [eventListener Sidebar Pane](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/devtools/front_end/elements/EventListenersSidebarPane.js) you can see that it is building a page rather than using `setObject`, making use of functions that are not available to an extension, and building this tree by itself (so there isn't really a clean builder for this view type that could be exposed. But the logic needed in such a sidebar page is easier to follow in [properties Sidebar Pane](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/devtools/front_end/elements/PropertiesSidebarPane.js?view=log) than `eventListener Sidebar Pane` if you don't need filter views/etc.)

To get the look, you could copy CSS out of the source for a page you provide via `setPage`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Pretty clear and explained answer. Big thanks for src links, will go through

Answer (score 2):

That is actually pretty straightforward. You have to get rid of the `title`, which is ***optional*** and, if provided, serves as the ***root*** of the expression tree. (source: [DevTools API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels)).

Hence, if you call `setObject` as follows :

```
var jsonObj = {
    first: {some: 'foo'},
    second: {some: 'bar'},
    third: {some: 'baz'}
};

sidebar.setObject(jsonObj);
```

you will get :

[image]

Notice though that the output is a bit different compared to the *Event Listeners* sidebar, as we are just outputting a JSON object. But that might fit your need, and personally I find useful the fact to have a summary without having to open each element. If you need exactly what is displayed in the *Event Listener* sidebar, I guess you have to look further `setObject`

Comment: Thanks for you response, yes, its workaround, but how to reach same output as `EventListeners` has ? my goal is to reach structured dropdown with objects inside absolutly the same as events. So the closest result i got `setObject` + title - it gives me the single entity, but i need a list. Any ideas ?

Comment: Then, you can't do that with the `setObject` API. You should go with `setPage` instead, that will open you much more possibilities for customization

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your feedback, looks the only way is  `setPage` .